# How to find the productId present in website(CDATA) using Beautiful Soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, cdata

I want to extract productId value(186852001461) from the given script or wherever id present on the website using beautiful soup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 /* <![CDATA[ */
var bv_single_product = {"prodname":"Honey Graham Gelato","productId":"186852001461"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

mycode

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
final = "https://www.talentigelato.com/products/honey-graham-gelato"
response = requests.get(final, timeout=35)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser") 
s = soup.findAll('script',attrs={'type': 'text/javascript'} )[17]
print(type(s))
html_content = str(s)
html_content = s.prettify()
print(html_content))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.string` and then a `regex` so you can dump the value to `json.loads()`.

Here's how:

```python
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

final = "https://www.talentigelato.com/products/honey-graham-gelato"
response = requests.get(final, timeout=35)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
s = soup.findAll('script', attrs={'type': 'text/javascript'})[17]
data = json.loads(re.search(r"single_product = ({.*})", s.string).group(1))
print(data["productId"])
```

Output:

```
186852001461
```

Comment: it's works can please explain how the regular expression used here (re.search(r"single_product = ({.*})", s.string).group(1))

Comment: The regex fetchesz everything inbetween the `{}`, with the brackets included.